# Using Solr with Encrypted (Tokenized) Index values

Tags: rest, encryption, solr, tokenize

I'm using Solr with a commercial encryption product.  The idea being that I would like to tokenize particular values in a csv file and then de-tokenize them using a REST API in some fashion.  Has any done this it all and if so how did you go about doing it.

My tokenized data looks like the following.

id,cat,name,price,inStock,author,series_t,sequence_i,genre_s
0553573403,book,n xcV3 Ha 3NgTmU5,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553579908,book,p qSi4F 5O 6YoRD,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",2,fantasy
055357342X,book,G e60GE gN g6JeFs,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",3,fantasy

What I need to do is run an Curl command or use an API to call the de-tokenisation server that then provides the de-tokenised values.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "de-tokenize"? Tokenizing and filtering is a one-way operation, and there is no way to restore the (exact) original content after the tokenization and filter process has run (unless you're only doing a KeywordTokenizer that keeps everything intact, but then you're not tokenizing at all).

Comment: "G e60GE gN g6JeFs" just looks like a value to store/retrieve like any string. But if you want to search it inside Solr somehow, make it clearer. The question is very hard to understand.